# Electrical circuit in circuitikz

Tags: circuitikz

How can I draw these in circuitikz.
Where can I find manual. Thanks for help
 [image]

Comment: What about [this](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf)? Please add what you've got so far.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a starting point. For details see the [`circuitikz` manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/circuitikz/circuitikzmanual.pdf). Note the use of polar coordinates, `(angle:distance)`, for this rotation-symmetric figure.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[europeanresistors]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
  \newcommand\R{3} % radius and side length of hexagon
  \foreach \a in {0,60,...,300}
     \draw (0,0) to[R,*-*] (\a:\R);
  \foreach \a in {0,120,180,300}
     \draw (\a:\R) to[R] (\a+60:\R);
  \draw (120:\R) to[voltmeter] (60:\R);
  \draw (240:\R) to[ammeter] (300:\R);
  \draw (0:\R) node[right] {B};
  \draw (180:\R) node[left] {A};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```